# Konsole Read/Write Access to PTY Device

Tags: kde

When I run something like:

```
$ konsole -e "sleep 30"
```

I get this message

```
Konsole is unable to open a PTY (pseudo teletype). It is likely that this is due to an incorrect configuration of the PTY devices. Konsole needs to have read/write access to the PTY devices.
```

But if I try to run this:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "sleep 30"
```

Then it is fine, and it does not throw any error.

How can I change the read/write access of the Konsole to the PTY devices?